# Sympy multivariate function analysis

Tags: sympy

I have some expression `expr` which is subject for analysis

```
c, l = symbols('c l', real=True, positive=True)
w = symbols('w', real=True)

expr = (w ** 2) / ((2 * c * l * w**4) - 3 * w**2 + (2/(c*l)))
expr
```

Output:

```
           2         
          w          
─────────────────────
       4      2    2 
2⋅c⋅l⋅w  - 3⋅w  + ───
                  c⋅l
```

I want to analyze this function w.r.t `w`. More specifically, I want to find the maximum value for the expression which should occur when

```
      1  
w = ─────
    √c⋅√l
```

I have tried solving it for when the derivative is zero:

```
solve(diff(expr, w))
```

Output:

```
⎡⎧    1  ⎫        ⎤
⎢⎪c: ────⎪, {w: 0}⎥
⎢⎨      2⎬        ⎥
⎢⎪   l⋅w ⎪        ⎥
⎣⎩       ⎭        ⎦
```

I am not sure how to use the output above and express this as a function of `l` and `c`. I would prefer

```
 2    1 
w  = ───
     c⋅l
```

Is there a more standard way of analyzing `expr` with respect to `w` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `solve` which symbol to solve for:

```
In [144]: solve(expr.diff(w), w)
Out[144]: 
⎡    -1      1  ⎤
⎢0, ─────, ─────⎥
⎣   √c⋅√l  √c⋅√l⎦
```